# php require field to remain empty

Tags: php

In my form field I have created a field that needs to remain blank to pass validation if there is any text in it, I need it to fail I

in my form I have added this in my validation

```
        $robotest = $_POST['robotest'];
```

then in my validation

```
        if ($robotest == ($_POST['robotest'])) {
            $errors[] = "Possible Spam.";
        }
```

how can I get it if equals and info in that field period it fails

Comment: You are not sounding quite clear enough with your question. Do you want the field `robotest` to be empty and if it is not empty, the validation fails?

Comment: BTW: there's no point of having parenthesis in `($_POST['robotest'])` part

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I think you mean no point of the parenthesis. The brackets are necessary.

Comment: @Pachonk yep. I corrected wording in my comment. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['robotest']) {
    $errors[] = "Possible Spam.";
}
```

[empty() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

If you want to allow for spaces, but no other characters, you can also wrap it in [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) like so:

```
if (!empty(trim($_POST['robotest'])) {
    $errors[] = "Possible Spam.";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is that the field `robotest` remains empty to pass your validation but should fail otherwise; then this snippet might help:

```
<?php

    // TRIM OUT WHITE SPACES JUST IN CASE SOMEONE ACCIDENTALLY PRESSED SPACE KEY
    // THEN CHECK IF THE FIELD IS EMPTY OR NOT....
    if( !empty( trim($_POST['robotest']) ){
        $errors[] = "Possible Spam.";        
    }
```